# SQLite group-by behaviour

Tags: sqlite, group-by

If a column in the SELECT clause is omitted from the GROUP BY clause, does SQLite group by the remaining columns (by default), and then return the value of the omitted column in the first row it evaluates?

For example, finding the TransactionId associated with the highest value per ProductId:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProductTransaction
(
   Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   ProductId INTEGER NOT NULL,
   TransactionType INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Value INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ProductTransaction (ProductId, TransactionType, Value)
VALUES (1, 7, 23), (1, 3, 12), (2, 4, 43), (1, 7, 5), (1, 10, 23), 
(3, 3, 23), (3, 2, 31), (1, 1, 23), (2, 5, 50),  (2, 6, 14), (1, 4, 23);

SELECT ProductId
, TransactionType
, MAX(Value)
FROM ProductTransaction
GROUP BY ProductId;

DELETE FROM ProductTransaction;
```

Running the previous statements gives me the TransactionType of 7 for ProductId 1 (Highest value 23).

However, if I add an the index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_TransType ON ProductTransaction(ProductId ASC, TransactionType ASC);
```

It returns the TransactionType 1, presumably because it's now ordering the rows according to the index.  Modifying the index supports this theory:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IDX_TransType ON ProductTransaction(ProductId ASC, TransactionType DESC);
```

It will now return TransactionType 10 for ProductId 1.

Is this behaviour by design, or is it just an unreliable side-effect?

EDIT:  It seems that it's an unreliable side-effect.  From the documentation:

> Each expression in the result-set is then evaluated once for each
>   group of rows. If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is
>   evaluated across all rows in the group. **Otherwise, it is evaluated
>   against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group**. If
>   there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set,
>   then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset

Comment: `TransactionType` is neither part of the `GROUP BY` nor used in an aggregate function, so which row SQLite uses for the `TransactionType` result is unspecified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQLite 3.7.11, using MAX() or MIN() will force any non-aggregated columns to come from the same row that matches the MAX()/MIN().

However, when there are multiple rows with the same largest/smalles value, it is still unspecified from which of those rows the other columns' values come. (SQLite's behaviour is consistent in this regard, but can change in different versions or with different database schemas.)